# JAVA: MAIL: How can i solve ClassNotFoundException : javax.mail.internet.AddressException?

Tags: java, email

I have some code to send an Email, It works  perfectly in my system. But the problem is I copied this program to another system and which gives the following error on runtime.

```
ClassNotFoundException : javax.mail.internet.AddressException
```

Note: Both System are Windows 7

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:javax.mail.internet.AddressException

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your dependency jar file are not download or it has some conflict with your dependency.

`javax.mail.internet.AddressException` locate in the `javax.mail-1.4.x.jar`.

Can you post your library list or your dependency?

Comment: activation,java-mail-1.4.4,javamail-smtp-1.4.2

Comment: can you download this tool http://jd.benow.ca/ to decompile your jar file and check that your jar file, java-mail.1.4.4 has `AddressException` class, if not, please replace it with this class.